# How to display a string value on multiple lines in a paragraph that contains <br> as a new line character

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to display a string in a paragraph and this string contains 
 for the purpose of displaying it new line.

But only thing i am getting is  br tag when i intend to break the line.

This is my **TypeScript** method.

```
   viewEmailMessage(messageId: number): void {
    console.log(messageId);
    this.previewEmailMessage = new EmailMessage();
    this.previewEmailMessage = this.emailMessageList.filter(item => item.id == messageId)[0];
    console.log(this.previewEmailMessage);
    this.previewEmailMessage.message = this.previewEmailMessage.message.replace(/(\n)+/g, '<br>');
    this.previewEmailMessage.signature = this.previewEmailMessage.signature.replace(/(\n)+/g,'<br>')
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="preview-send" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">


    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Preview</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="preview-content">
          <div class="title">
            <h2>{{previewEmailMessage.title}}</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="subject">
            <p>{{previewEmailMessage.subject}}</p>
          </div>

          <div class="description">
            <p>{{previewEmailMessage.message}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="signature-wrap"> 
            <p>{{previewEmailMessage.signature}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn default-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result: [image: Actual Output]

How can I display this on new line whenever line break occur in html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the paragraph content with `[innerHTML]`:

```
<p [innerHTML]="previewEmailMessage.message"></p>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojnact) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the salesforce API, you can try using `this.previewEmailMessage.HtmlBody` instead.
Can't immediately remember if there was a signature HTML field as well.